# Test if a promise is resolved or rejected with Jasmine in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, promise

I know how to do it in Mocha but want to know how to do it with Jasmine. 
I tried this

```js
describe('test promise with jasmine', function() {
    it('expects a rejected promise', function() {
        var promise = getRejectedPromise();

        // return expect(promise).toBe('rejected');
        return expect(promise.inspect().state).toBe('rejected');
    });
});
```

However, the state is always `pending` and, of course, the test fails. I couldn't find any example online that I could make it work.

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

To test asynchronous code with jasmine you should use [its async syntax](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node#async-tests), e.g.:

```
describe('test promise with jasmine', function(done) {
    var promise = getRejectedPromise();

    promise.then(function() {
      // Promise is resolved
      done(new Error('Promise should not be resolved'));
    }, function(reason) {
      // Promise is rejected
      // You could check rejection reason if you want to
      done(); // Success
    });
});
```

Comment: Great!  What if you wanted to check the contents of the error being rejected?  For some reason I keep getting either `Error: Actual is not a function` or `Expected { _subscribers : [  ], _state : 0, _detail : {  } } to throw error of type Function.`  Thanks!

Comment: great! yep, thats what im doing... but if i do `expect(reason).toEqual('someerrorstring');` i get the errors i mentioned...

Comment: @Cmag I would recommend to inspect rejection reason manually at first, to make sure that it's really what you're expecting it to be. Just use `console.log` or something like that.

Comment: console.log shows it as [Error blahblah: blah], but if i match it with toEqual(''), it borks..

Comment: @Cmag It's because you're matching Error object with a string.

Comment: yep, got that ... how should i match the error object :)

Comment: @Cmag I would suggest checking that it's an instance of `Error` class and that it contains `msg` property with expected error message.

Comment: Instead of `done(new Error('Promise should not be resolved'));`, I'd rather write `throw new Error('Promise should not be resolved');`

Comment: @sl3dg3 in this case we should also `return` resulting promise and ensure that jasmine can handle promise rejections correctly. Jasmine had no build-in promise support when I used it for the last time. I switched to mocha a couple of years ago and never used jasmine since, so I'm not aware of the current situation there. If jasmine support promises now, then your proposal is indeed the better alternative to my answer.

Comment: But if the promise is already rejected, the the ''callbacks" success and failures never are gonna be called no? On my code is not working because im returning a rejected promise return $q.reject('reason')

Comment: @jjalonso you are wrong, A+ promise standard demands that appropriate `.then(onresolve, onreject)` callback should be called even if the promise is already resolved/rejected.

Comment: I'm maintaining an older library using jasmine 2.0.3 and `done(new Error('Promise should not be resolved'));` does not cause the test case to fail. I've replaced it with `expect('Promise should not be resolved').toBeUndefined();` followed by `done()` but it doesn't seem elegant.

Comment: Starting from jasmine 2.7, I suggest to use the async/await style (see my answer below.

Comment: As of jasmine ^2.3, I can not pass parameters into the done function. It would be better to use `done.fail(new Error('error message'))`. [Reference to documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction#section-54)

Comment: If you are using jasmine 3 and above, you can pass an error parameter in the done function. [Reference to documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async)

Comment: This used to be a good answer but at this point I'd expect everybody to be on a new enough version to use `expectAsync`, which allows you to write tests that "look like Jasmine".

Answer (score 58):

you can now use `expectAsync()`

Expecting success:

```
it('expect result', async () => {
   ...
   await expectAsync(someAsyncFunction(goodInput)).toBeResolved(expectedResponse)
})
```

Expecting failure:

```
it('expect result', async () => {
   ...
   await expectAsync(someAsyncFunction(badInput)).toBeRejectedWith(expectedResponse)
})
```

Comment: Additional note: It is *crucial* to *always* use `await` (`await expectAsync(...)`) - otherwise the test will always succeed, no matter if the promise is rejected or not, and no matter if the test expects it to be rejected or resolved!

Comment: Actually not true. It can also just be returned from within the spec.

`return expectAsync(pi).toBeResolvedTo(3.14);`

Comment: This is the most idiomatic answer and should be accepted.  (The current accepted answer was good when it was given, but your solution is objectively better now.)

Answer (score 7):

jasmine 2.7 onwards supports returning promises, and would have its fulfilled state tested.

**To test for rejection:**

```
it('test promise with jasmine', async () => {
    try {
        await getRejectedPromise();
    } catch (err) {
        return;
    }

    throw new Error('Promise should not be resolved');
});
```

or yet:

```
it('test promise with jasmine', async () => {
    await getRejectedPromise()
        .then(
            () => Promise.reject(new Error('Promise should not be resolved')), 
            () => {});
});
```

**To verify the actual message**, besides the usual `instanceof/toBe()`, place inside the `catch`:

```
expect(() => { throw err }).toThrow(new MyCustomError('Custom error message'));
```

The benefit from this approach is to have a nicer fail message on the test output.

> Expected function to throw MyCustomError: Custom error message, but it threw Another error message.

Somewhat better than the usual output.

**To test for resolved (can't be simpler):**

```
it('test promise with jasmine', async () => {
    await getRejectedPromise();
});
```

Comment: try/catch is the ugliest coding construct in almost every programming language, imo

Comment: @AlexanderMills I know you're kidding, but I' switched from plain promises/then to async/await long ago. Ofc I use the "old way" when it makes sense.

Comment: If you add a promise above `getRejectedPromise()` this code will swallow errors, because there is no check for what type of error occurs in the error handler.

Comment: Therefore this code is not really for general use, it's "pretty" shorthand.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `finally` block to test promise state:

```
it('should resolve if auth succeed', (done)=>{
    var p = server.login('user', 'password');
    p.finally(()=>{
        expect(p.isFulfilled()).toBeTruthy();
        done();
    });
});
```

You can use `isFulfilled` to check if promise was fulfilled and `value` method to check the fulfillment value. Corresponding methods for rejection are `isRejected` and `reason`.

Comment: With this method, how to you check if the promise was rejected, and check the rejection message?

Comment: @RuiMarques you can use `isRejected` and `reason` methods. I updated my answer.

Comment: `finally()`, `isFulfilled()` aren't standard (as of 2017). Please edit your answer to specify external requirements.

Comment: This answer is wrong in several ways: (1) `isFulfilled()` is *not* an official method of `Promise` according to the ECMAScript standard. (2) Even if it were, it would always return `true` inside `finally`, as `fulfilled` means the promise is either _rejected_ or _resolved_, which is always true when `finally` is called.

Answer (score 0):

@Leonid's answer is correct, but you can simplify like so, and use only promises:

```
it('test promise with jasmine', function() {

    return getRejectedPromise().then(function() {
      // Promise should not be resolved, so we reject it
      return Promise.reject(new Error('Promise should not be resolved'));
    })
    .catch(function(err){
       if(!/Promise should not be resolved/.test(err && err.message)){
          return Promise.reject(err);
       }
    })
})
```

Comment: Agreed. I've withdrawn my upvote because the ugly catch clause. Someone else downvoted probably because this note was missing and thought it wouldn't work.

Comment: The catch clause is necessary for it to work correctly, it's the normal API for Promises, I don't think it's ugly...would you code something incorrectly just to make it more beautiful? Lol idk

Comment: The test() is for an error thrown a couple lines above, it's ugly and lazy coding. See my answer.

Comment: @AndréWerlang eh, sometimes you have test for error messages, sometimes it's necessary to use catch blocks, perhaps not in this case, but I think mine is more generic, if you need to add more promises to the chain later down the road.