# Test if a promise is resolved or rejected with Jasmine 1.3 in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, promise, jasmine-node

I am using the npm library jasmine-node for unit testing of my javascript code. As far as I understand, it uses Jasmine 1.3.

Most of my code involves asynchronous Promises (using ES6 built-in promises, not one of the 3rd party Promise libraries). I have read that Jasmine 2 has a method called done() that you can call from the "then" or "catch" call on your promise. What can I do in Jasmine 1.3? Is there a way to simulate this? Or is there a better approach or different branch of jasmine-node?

See this question:
[Test if a promise is resolved or rejected with Jasmine in Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164404/test-if-a-promise-is-resolved-or-rejected-with-jasmine-in-nodejs)

Comment: As far as I know, Jasmine 1.x does not have good asynchronous test support. If at all possible, I would move to Jasmine 2.x. It is wayyyy better for a number of reasons. Another possibility, which is also not a good one is to use mocking and stubbing of all of your async code so that it can be executed synchronously in the same tick. It seems that 1.3 does indeed have async support, but a bit messy. http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support

Comment: I would love to move to Jasmine 2, but I like the convenience of the npm module, which is still at 1.3. I came across a module called Jasmine.Async that looks promising that makes it possible to call a "done()" method like Jasmine 2, but I am still researching.

Comment: I think you're mistaken. The jasmine-core npm module is the one you want. https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid using the jasmine-node module. It is no longer maintained (last commit was over two years ago, and the PRs are piling up). Instead you should be using [jasmine-core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-core), the official bundling of jasmine.

And honestly, the bundlings of these packages is not too clear. You actually want to install the [jasmine](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine) package. This provides you with command line tools that help you provision a project for use with jasmine and gives you commands to run the specs. Eg (from the documentation):

Local installation:

```
npm install --save-dev jasmine
```

To initialize a project for Jasmine

```
./node_modules/.bin/jasmine init
```

To seed your project with some examples

```
./node_modules/.bin/jasmine examples
```

To run your test suite

```
./node_modules/.bin/jasmine
```

You can also choose to install jasmine globally like this:

```
npm install -g jasmine
```

This way, you can avoid prefixing each invocation with `./node_modules/.bin/`. But, I prefer using a locally installed instance for all project dependencies. This ensures that you use the same version of dependencies that your project expects.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this.

Comment: I have to type "./node_modules/.bin/jasmine init" as the process you outlined did not modify my path, but otherwise it worked fine.

Comment: the `npm install -g jasmine` should install it globally. But, you are best off using the locally installed version if it is a project dependency. I will update my answer.