# Error: Uncaught (in promise) when jasmine testing Angular component behavior on rejected promise

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs, jasmine, zone

I'm using angular@12.2.13, jasmine-core@3.10.1, karma@6.3.9

I'm trying to test my Angular component unhappy ngOnInit behavior mapping a promise to an observable, i.e. the catchError block:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeEditConcernFormGroup$ = from(this.concernService.getConcernById(this.currentConcernId)).pipe(
      tap(() => (this.loadingError = null)),
      switchMap((receivedConcern) => this.handleReceivedConcern(receivedConcern)),
      map(({ concern, concernConfiguration }) => this.concernFormService.createConcernFormGroup(concernConfiguration.concerns, concern)),
      tap((formGroup) => (this.editConcernFormGroup = formGroup)),
      catchError( err => {
        this.loadingError = err;
        return EMPTY;
      }));
  }
```

In my test I'm overriding the service method with a mock implementation that rejects a promise:

```
 it('should set loadingError if getConcernById fails', fakeAsync(() => {
   const errorMessage = 'Oops!...';
   concernService.getConcernById = jasmine.createSpy().and.callFake(() =>  Promise.reject(errorMessage));
   component.ngOnInit();
   tick(100); // promise reject being raised here
   expect(component.loadingError).toEqual(errorMessage);
}));
```

Unfortunately on `tick(100)` the test fails with the following stack trace:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Oops!...
    Error: Oops!...
        at ConcernServiceMock.<anonymous> (src/app/administration/pages/concern/edit-concern/edit-concern.component.spec.ts:184:98)
        at SpyStrategy.exec (node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:9326:39)
        at SpyStrategyDispatcher.exec (node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:8845:23)
        at spy (node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:8725:46)
        at node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:8698:16
        at ConcernServiceMock.wrap [as getConcernById] (node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:8771:20)
        at EditConcernComponent.ngOnInit (src/app/administration/pages/concern/edit-concern/edit-concern.component.ts:125:76)
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (src/app/administration/pages/concern/edit-concern/edit-concern.component.spec.ts:185:21)
        at UserContext.fakeAsyncFn (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:2032:1)
        at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:372:1)
        at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:287:1)
        at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:371:1)
        at Zone.run (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:134:1)
        at runInTestZone (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:582:1)
```

`catchError` is never being executed. It seems `from` from RxJS cannot deal with rejected Promises. The error bubbles up and then it hits the test execution which finally fails the test. No `expect` is being executed.

As far as I analysed it, it does not seem the be a zone.js issue. At least

```
Zone[Zone.__symbol__['ignoreConsoleErrorUncaughtError']] = true;
```

didn't help.

What am I doing wrong here? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55822482/2358409

Comment: @uminder unfortunately not. I'm not really testing an async function here. ngOnInit synchronously subscribes to the observable. I previously also tried using jasmine's done-function instead of asyncAwait (similar to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27165104/1165421) but it showed the same issue.